# Scaling a websocket broadcast server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, scaling, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a node js websocket server that acts as broadcast server connecting N clients.
It uses memory to keep a state.

I wanna scale it. I did some research and it seems that ALB + ECS should work.

My questions are:

- Is it possible for the ALB to redirect an incoming request to the right container? If so, how to do that? Keep mapping in a database?
- In this configuration, can I use ECS with Fargate and still be able to redirect to the right container?

I'm open to other ways to scale this.